# Why Mathematica gives a wrong result for number form of a simple expression?

Tags: numerics, numerical-value

I ask Mathematica number form of
$$\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{2}{3} \pi  \left(2 \pi -\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$

```
N[  Sin[(4 π^2)/3] + Sin[2/3 π (-(3/2) + 2 π)] ]
```

and it gives $-\text{1.1102230246251565$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16}$, but it is evident that it is zero
$$\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}-\pi \right)=\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}\right)=0$$

My question is that do we always have to give Mathematica a WorkingPrecision to get the correct result?

Comment: Around the numerical value of the intermediates, `-1.11*10^-16` is the resolution of a double precision floating point number. This result is off from zero by at most the epsilon between the two consecutive floating point numbers, and should be taken as such. Machine precision has no adaptability available to determine that this is insufficient.

Comment: The command `N[Sin[(4 \[Pi]^2)/3] + Sin[2/3 \[Pi] (-(3/2) + 2 \[Pi])], 100]` produces `0.*10^-149` and a warning "N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating Sin[(4 \[Pi]^2)/3]+Sin[2/3 \[Pi] (-(3/2)+2 \[Pi])].".

Comment: See [`Machine Precision Numbers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#22593)

Answer (score 4):

`Simplify` gives the correct result.

```
Simplify[Sin[(4 π^2)/3] + Sin[2/3 π (-(3/2) + 2 π)]]   (* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sin[(4 π^2)/3] + Sin[2/3 π (-(3/2) + 2 π)] // ExpandAll
```